# Do I have to abort a System.Threading.Thread?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I wonder if I have to stop a (UI-)Thread (called from a native C++ Project) after I am finished with it. Or can I just let it go so as ASP.NET does this job for me?

I call and create the `System.Threading.Thread` like this.

```
Thread viewerThread = new Thread(delegate ()
{
    Window window = new MyCustomWPFWindow();
    window.Show();
    System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
});

this.UIThread = viewerThread;

viewerThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
viewerThread.Start();
```

I know there is a `Thread.Abort()` Method, but do I really have to abort it or is there a better method or can I just let it go and let .NET handle this.

Comment: When a thread finishes the routine it is running, it will automatically dispose of itself

Comment: UI thread in `ASP.NET`?

Comment: even stranger, what Window what GetDialog what DIspatcher in ASP? Did you mean WPF instead? ooh.. or maybe is that you create and show some windows from within an asp web application by chance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should avoid `Thread.Abort()`, use this only when a third-party component blocks a thread. Even then, figure out why it hangs. *(`Thread.Abort()` == Evil)* You should always design your threading without `Abort()`.

---

You should shutdown the Dispatcher if you want to stop thread. Here's an example on how you could implement it.

```
// a field to store the guiDispatcher.
Dispatcher guiDispatcher;

// wait event.
ManualResetEvent dispatcherInitialized = new ManualResetEvent(false);

Thread viewerThread = new Thread(delegate ()
{
    Window window = GetDialog(configuration);
    window.Show();
    // get a/the dispatcher of this thread.
    guiDispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;

    // dispatcher initialized. Set wait event.
    dispatcherInitialized.Set();

    // run dispatcher.
    System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
});

viewerThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
viewerThread.Start();
dispatcherInitialized.WaitOne();

// ......

// when you want to terminate the thread, just shutdown the dispatcher.
guiDispatcher.BeginInvokeShutdown(DispatcherPriority.Normal);
// you might want to wait until the thread is terminated.
viewerThread.Join();
```

---

If the dispatcher stops by it self, the thread will be cleaned-up. If the dispatcher doesn't stop (which prevents the application from terminating), you can add `viewerThread.IsBackground = true;`

Comment: in your example is the `window.Show` blocking the main UI thread?

Comment: @toddmo nope, `window.Show()` does not block the thread. it isn't the model of showing (like `ShowDialog()`)  `System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();` will block the thread _(it is a messageloop)_ and will be terminated by the `BeginInvokeShutdown()`